# Why is this integral equality true? $\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}|a+be^{it}|dt=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left||a|+|b|e^{it}\right|dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, self-learning

I was reading an article, and while proving a proposition, they state that if $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, then due to periodicity we have
$$\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}|a+be^{it}|dt=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left||a|+|b|e^{it}\right|dt$$
I don't see it clearly, and I'm trying to see why is this true.

The only thing that comes to me is writting $$|a+be^{it}|=\left||a|e^{it_1}+|b|e^{it_2}e^{it}\right|$$ 
but I don't know what to do from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:** Following on from what you have done, firstly, try and convince yourself that

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left||a|e^{it_1} + |b|e^{i(t\color{red}{+t_2})}\right|\, dt = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left| |a|e^{it_1} + |b| e^{it}\right|\, dt.$$

(This uses periodicity.)

Secondly, factor out $e^{it_1}$ from the modulus of the right-hand side above and use periodicity similarly to above to note that

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left||a|+ |b|e^{i(t\color{red}{-t_1})}\right|\, dt = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left| |a|+ |b| e^{it}\right|\, dt.$$

Comment: Note that if:
$$a=a_1+ia_2$$
$$b=b_1+ib_2$$
then:
$$|a+be^{it}|=|(a_1+b_1e^{it})+i(a_2+b_2e^{it})|=\sqrt{(a_1+b_1e^{it})^2+(a_2+b_2e^{it})^2}$$
and (using $c_1+ic_2=e^{it}$ to simplify):
$$||a|+|b|e^{it}|=|\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}+\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2}e^{it}|=\left|\left(\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}+c_1\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2}\right)+ic_2\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2}\right|$$
Could see if anything follows from this?